# Dlang chomp() not working on certain delimiters

Tags: string, d

The statement `writefln("%s", chomp("Hello world", "orld"))`
produces the correct output `Hello w`.

However, the delimiters ":" and "," don't get chomped.

```
writefln("%s", chomp("Hello : world", ":"))
```

outputs `Hello : world`

The docs for std.string.chomp don't mention anything about reserved chars, unless I'm misunderstanding something.  Is this a bug or working as intended?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chomp` strips off the ending delimiter of the string and in your case `"Hello world"` of course ends with `"orld"`

However `"Hello : world"` does not end with `":"` and in fact if you want it to end with anything remotely related to it then it ends with `": world"`

If this would have to work with `chomp` then it should be `"Hello world:"`

```
writefln("%s", chomp("Hello world:", ":")); // It should be like this
```

You can also use `chompPrefix` for starting delimiters rather than ending.

If you want to remove `":"` from the string however, then you can use `replace` from `std.array`

```
writefln("%s", replace("Hello : world", ":" ""));
// Output: "Hello  world"
```

Comment: Thanks, guess I misunderstood the purpose of chomp

Comment: You're welcome! Too be honest it should have been named chompSuffix, because chomp itself means to chew or munch which would make sense to work like what you wanted it to.